# multiple modules different name same ports

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to instantiate 4 transceivers of Xilinx so I have 4 the same port modules but different module names. I want to use "generate" I tried nested `ifdef to enclose the module names and other technique and did not work. I do not want to instantiate multiple modules

generate loop will generate multiple instances of the same module .. here we need to instantiate different module names with the same ports. each module will target an IP location on the die

is there is a way in Generate?
here an example of what I tried

```
 localparam [3:0]index[3:0] = { 4'h3,4'h2,4'h1,4'h0}  ;
  genvar genid;
  generate for (genid = 0; genid < 3; genid = genid + 1) begin : gen_common_container
    
`ifdef mac0  
if (index[genid] == 4'h0) 
  freq_cntr_0
 else if (index[genid] == 4'h1) 
  freq_cntr_1
 else if (index[genid] == 4'h2) 
  freq_cntr_2
`endif

//freq_cntr_cm   freq_cntr_inst_cm
freq_cntr_inst_cm (  // system clock & resets
   .i_clk      (sys_clk  ),
   .i_rst      (sys_rst  ),
   // clock to measure
   .i_varclk   (gt_tx_usrclk2  ),
   // measured frequency   (i_clk domain)
   .o_clkval   (freq_cnt  )
);

end
endgenerate
```

Comment: There is no way to do what you want in verilog. You can instantiate the same module multiple times in a generate block. However your example seems to seek for away to choose between different definition names in a generate block. This is impossible. Your best bet is to manually list all 4 instances and get rid of the generate block. BTW, o_clkval seems to be an output, right? you are trying to drive it from multiple drivers this way in any case.

Answer (score 0):

So long as all the ports will always be the same. You can put the port list in a `` `define `` macro or in an `` `include `` file.

Mix and match example that worked on [EDAplaygound](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/8aGq):

```
localparam [3:0]index[3:0] = { 4'h3,4'h1,4'h2,4'h0}  ;
genvar genid;
`define freq_cntr_inst_cm_macro \
  freq_cntr_inst_cm \
  // system clock & resets \
  .i_clk      (sys_clk  ), \
  .i_rst      (sys_rst  ), \
  // clock to measure \
  .i_varclk   (gt_tx_usrclk2  ), \
  // measured frequency   (i_clk domain) \
  .o_clkval   (freq_cnt  )

generate for (genvar genid = 0; genid < 3; genid = genid + 1) begin : gen_common_container
  case(index[genid])
    4'h0 : freq_cntr_0 `freq_cntr_inst_cm_macro;
    4'h1 : freq_cntr_1 `include "freq_cntr_inst_cm.vh";
    4'h2 : freq_cntr_2 `freq_cntr_inst_cm_macro;
    4'h3 : freq_cntr_3 `include "freq_cntr_inst_cm.vh";
    default : freq_cntr_0 `freq_cntr_inst_cm_macro;
  endcase
end
endgenerate
```

*freq_cntr_inst_cm.vh* :

```
freq_cntr_inst_cm (
// system clock & resets
.i_clk      (sys_clk  ),
.i_rst      (sys_rst  ),
// clock to measure
.i_varclk   (gt_tx_usrclk2  ),
// measured frequency   (i_clk domain)
.o_clkval   (freq_cnt  )
);
```